# Modelling a database involving Customers, Projects, Employees, Drawings and Revisions

Tags: database-design

I am working on a database based application and am also looking for some feedback on how to organize the relevant tables. The application handles customer project info and the projects technical drawings.

**The scenario**

- Each *Project* is made up of *n* quantity of *Drawing Sets*, which have *n* quantity of *Drawings* with *n* quantity of *Revisions* each  made by *Employees* "a", "b", and "c".
- Each *Project* needs to be associated with the *Customer* it belongs to  and the *Employees* who worked on the project, both of which have arbitrary *ID Numbers*.

**My considerations**

Having "Index Tables" to link a `customers` and `employees` table with a `projects` table seems like an obvious choice but since the projects essential have a nested structure I have become unsure about how to continue.

**Information structure**

If working up-to-bottom, a *Revision* would have a unique *ID* structured as

- (*Project No.*)-(*Set No.*)-(*Drawing No.*)-(*Revision No.*)

and a *Drawing ID* would be

- (*Project No.*)-(*Set No.*)-(*Drawing No.*) and so on.

The *Numbers* are made up as follows:

- *Project*: *Sales Order Number, Line Item, Release*
- *Drawing Set*: *Type, Set Sub Type*
- *Drawing*: *Page Number, Section Number*
- *Revision*: *Rev Number, Minor Rev, Build Rev*

**Further considerations**

All the *Projects* would go into a table just fine with a compound primary key being made up of the *Sales Order Number*, *Line Item*, and *Release*, the *Project ID*. But If a *Drawing Set*'s primary key was a compound key made up in part by a compound key from another table the number of columns start to get out of hand.

This is where I get torn with using "Index Tables" to link *Drawings* with *Drawing Sets* and *Revisions*, or make a new `drawings` table and a `revisions` table for each *Drawing Set* or just for each *Project*. I have read that surrogate primary keys would be better than natural keys but for some reason I still feel like having project-specific tables is better than grouping all *Drawings* from all *Projects* into a single table. I'm fairly new to this whole database thing so I'm not even sure if another solution even exists but some feedback on how you would approach this would be helpful.